# Modifying Root – Big Sur

Tags: macos, mount, root, macos-bigsur

I have:

1. booted in 'recovery mode' (cmd + R)
2. disabled SIP (`csrutil disable`)
3. rebooted
4. mounted the root volume (`sudo mount -o nobrowse -t apfs /dev/disk1s1 /Users/user/Mount`)
5. replaced files in `/Users/user/Mount`
6. created a snapshot (`sudo bless --folder /Users/user/Mount/System/Library/CoreServices --bootefi --create-snapshot`)
7. rebooted (with SIP still disabled)

On restart, however, root files are quite unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect it may have been that you used disable instead of authenticated-root disable (though I haven't played with big Sur enough to be sure). See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395508/can-i-mount-the-root-system-filesystem-as-writable-in-big-sur Also check https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375603/catalina-not-allowing-to-change-read-write-permissions-despite-having-sip-disabl for more background

Comment: I need to have 'csrutil disable' to be able to give myself the permissions to change the mounted files. I also used 'csrutil authenticated-root disable' and it had not effect.